# ContosoUniversityDotNetCore-Pages SliceFixture with AutoMapper

Tags: unit-testing, automapper, mediatr

My Create handler uses `AutoMapper` to map from command to entity.

```
public async Task<int> Handle(Command command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var entity = _mapper.Map<ExampleEntity>(command);
    await _db.ExampleEntity.AddAsync(entity, cancellationToken);
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    return entity.Id;
}
```

My test looks like this

```
var command = new Create.Command
{
    Name = "Example 1",
     ...
};
var id = await _fixture.SendAsync(command, mapper);
id.ShouldNotBeNull();
```

This is the SliceFixture

```
[CollectionDefinition(nameof(SliceFixture))]
public class SliceFixtureCollection : ICollectionFixture<SliceFixture> { }

public class SliceFixture : IAsyncLifetime
{
    private readonly Checkpoint _checkpoint;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

    public SliceFixture()
    {
        _factory = new ContosoTestApplicationFactory();
        _configuration = _factory.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
        _scopeFactory = _factory.Services.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
        _checkpoint = new Checkpoint();
    }

    public class ContosoTestApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((_, configBuilder) =>
            {
                configBuilder.AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection", _connectionString}
                });
            });
        }

        private readonly string _connectionString = "";
    }

    public async Task ExecuteScopeAsync(Func<IServiceProvider, Task> action)
    {
        using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
        var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SchoolContext>();

        try
        {
            await dbContext.BeginTransactionAsync();
            await action(scope.ServiceProvider);
            await dbContext.CommitTransactionAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            dbContext.RollbackTransaction(); 
            throw;
        }
    }

    public async Task<T> ExecuteScopeAsync<T>(Func<IServiceProvider, Task<T>> action)
    {
        using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope();
        var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SchoolContext>();

        try
        {
            await dbContext.BeginTransactionAsync();
            var result = await action(scope.ServiceProvider);
            await dbContext.CommitTransactionAsync();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            dbContext.RollbackTransaction();
            throw;
        }
    }

    public Task ExecuteDbContextAsync(Func<SchoolContext, Task> action) => ExecuteScopeAsync(sp => action(sp.GetService<SchoolContext>()));

    public Task ExecuteDbContextAsync(Func<SchoolContext, ValueTask> action) => ExecuteScopeAsync(sp => action(sp.GetService<SchoolContext>()).AsTask());

    public Task ExecuteDbContextAsync(Func<SchoolContext, IMediator, Task> action) => ExecuteScopeAsync(sp => action(sp.GetService<SchoolContext>(), sp.GetService<IMediator>()));

    public Task<T> ExecuteDbContextAsync<T>(Func<SchoolContext, Task<T>> action) => ExecuteScopeAsync(sp => action(sp.GetService<SchoolContext>()));

    public Task<T> ExecuteDbContextAsync<T>(Func<SchoolContext, ValueTask<T>> action) => ExecuteScopeAsync(sp => action(sp.GetService<SchoolContext>()).AsTask());

    public Task<T> ExecuteDbContextAsync<T>(Func<SchoolContext, IMediator, Task<T>> action) => ExecuteScopeAsync(sp => action(sp.GetService<SchoolContext>(), sp.GetService<IMediator>()));

    public Task InsertAsync<T>(params T[] entities) where T : class
    {
        return ExecuteDbContextAsync(db =>
        {
            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                db.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            }
            return db.SaveChangesAsync();
        });
    }

    public Task<T> FindAsync<T>(int id)
        where T : class, IEntity
    {
        return ExecuteDbContextAsync(db => db.Set<T>().FindAsync(id).AsTask());
    }

    public Task<TResponse> SendAsync<TResponse>(IRequest<TResponse> request)
    {
        return ExecuteScopeAsync(sp =>
        {
            var mediator = sp.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();

            return mediator.Send(request);
        });
    }

    public Task SendAsync(IRequest request)
    {
        return ExecuteScopeAsync(sp =>
        {
            var mediator = sp.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();

            return mediator.Send(request);
        });
    }

    private int _courseNumber = 1;

    public int NextCourseNumber() => Interlocked.Increment(ref _courseNumber);

    public Task InitializeAsync() => _checkpoint.Reset(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

    public Task DisposeAsync()
    {
        _factory?.Dispose();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

When I run the test I get -

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

because `_mapper` is null.

I know I probably need to modify the `SliceFixture` but can't figure out what to do.

I was looking to implement Jimmy’s example [here](https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversityDotNetCore-Pages/blob/master/ContosoUniversity.IntegrationTests/SliceFixture.cs) with the additional `AutoMapper` implementation.

Comment: The shown snippets of code do not provide enough context to be able solve your problem.

Comment: I added a link to the fixture code I wanted to use